# Issues configuring CacheTool & PHP-FPM

Tags: php, fpm, opcache, php-deployer

I'm trying to use the [CacheTool recipe](https://deployer.org/recipes/cachetool.html) from Deployer.

I'm having issues with the configuration of cachetool.

Using WHM / cPanel and PHP version is PHP 7.4 (`ea-php74`).

`set('cachetool', '/var/cpanel/php-fpm/<username>/sock');`
Results in the following error:

```
In AbstractCommand.php line 39:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Extension `Zend OPcache` is not loaded
                                                                                                                                                                                   
opcache:reset
```

Using a specific socket file for the domain:
`set('cachetool', '/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/<hashed-domain>.sock');`

results in

```
In FastCGI.php line 114:
Error: File not found.
opcache:reset
```

Trying with the IP:
`set('cachetool', '127.0.0.1:9000');`
returns

```
================                                                                                               
In FastCGI.php line 143:                       
FastCGI error: Unable to connect to FastCGI application: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:9000)                                                                                                             
In Socket.php line 320:
Unable to connect to FastCGI application: Connection refused

In Socket.php line 270:                                  
stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:9000 (Connection refused)

opcache:reset
```

I'm a bit lost in all configuration files/possibilities, anyone who can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define `--fcgi-chroot` and/or `--tmp-dir` options to make it work.

From [Readme][1]:

> Troubleshooting
>
> ---
>
> > [RuntimeException]
> > Error: Unable to open primary script: /dev/shm/cachetool-584743c678dbb.php (No such file or directory)
> > Status: 404 Not Found
> > Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> > No input file specified.
>
> This means that cachetool could not write to `/dev/shm` provide a
> directory that cachetool can write to through `php cachetool.phar --tmp-dir=/writable/dir` or configuration.

...

> - To connect to a chrooted fastcgi server you need to set
>   `--fcgi-chroot` and `--tmp-dir` parameters
>
> ```sh
>  php cachetool.phar opcache:status --fcgi=/var/run/php5-fpm.sock --fcgi-chroot=/path/to/chroot --tmp-dir=/path/to/chroot/tmp
> ```